# Is that possible to get facebook page data with app token in Graph-API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is that possible to get page data with app token? When I try to do so it writes:
"(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review."
So I suppose that it possible, but only after review. I have tried to send app to review but it was rejected. So should I try one more time, or it's impossible to get page data with app token?

Answer (score 0):

Once your app was reviewed and approved for Page Public Content Access (which requires Business Verification) you can use an app token to query public page data.